# Define custom root json node on ember serializer

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm trying to get brands items from my REST API with ember; but my API response does not match with ember-data expected. for example:

My model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    isActive: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

My API url: http://localhost:3000/api/brands
its response with:

```
{"success":true,
     "data":[
        {"id":1,"name":"Mine","isActive":true,"createdAt":"2017-04-23T20:36:49.000Z","updatedAt":"2017-04-23T20:44:32.000Z"},
        {"id":2,"name":"forever","isActive":true,"createdAt":"2017-04-23T20:41:14.000Z","updatedAt":"2017-04-23T20:43:57.000Z"}
    ]
}
```

but, Ember is expecting some like this:

```
"brands": [{

    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo",
    "isActive": "foo"

}]
```

I'm trying to change the root json node in serializer called brand.js, but I can not make it work. :(

here my serializer/brand.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

});
```

and my adapters/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin';
import config from '../config/environment';


export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {  
    host: `${config.host}`,
    namespace: `${config.namespace}`,
    authorizer: 'authorizer:custom'
});
```

on browser console this message appears:

```
WARNING: Encountered "success" in payload, but no model was found for model name "success" (resolved model name using vanely-web@serializer:brand:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("success"))
WARNING: Encountered "data" in payload, but no model was found for model name "datum" (resolved model name using vanely-web@serializer:brand:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("data"))
```

How can I say to ember where the correct data is?.Some help is appreciated.

Sorry if my English is not well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already did, you can override the RESTSerializer for every model.

What you want to achieve is response normalization. You can normalize your response by overriding `normalizeResponse` in your serializer ([see the docs](https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizeResponse)):

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

const {
  RESTSerializer
} = DS;

const {
  get
} = Ember;

export default RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    // Only do normalization for reading:
    if(requestType !== 'createRecord' && requestType !== 'updateRecord' && requestType !== 'deleteRecord') {
      // Do your normalization here. For example (not tested):
      payload = {
        brands: get(payload, 'data')
      };
    }

    return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
  }
});
```

Instead of overriding `normalizeResponse`, you could also override the [other normalization methods](https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html).